# SQL grouping top 10 highest multiple column expressions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by

The following returns the highest bar value for each top 10 foo, ordering top to bottom by that value:

`SELECT top 10 foo, MAX(bar) AS Count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY Count DESC;`

How could this pattern be extended to accompany multiple grouping column expressions? 
i.e to return highest bar1, bar2, bar3 .. values for each foo all ordered as DESC.

Updated according to my scenario, please find the below query and the corresponding output:

`select top 10 Name as Rg_name, no as Rg_no, MAX(IOPS_Read) as MAX_Riops, MAX(IOPS_Write) as MAX_Wiops, MAX(IOPS_ReadWrite) as MAX_RWiops
from rgs
GROUP BY Name, no
ORDER BY MAX_Riops DESC, MAX_Wiops DESC, MAX_RWiops DESC`

```
Rg_name           Rg_no  MAX_Riops MAX_Wiops  MAX_RWiops

VMWARE_RG12       34     5444      117        5461
VM_RG_02          2      5436      567        5512
VM_RG_05          11     5327      545        5349
VM_RG_11          14     3623      644        3631
VMWARE_VDI_RG7    25     2530      908        2630
VMWARE_RG_4 16    2182   401       2189       107
EXCHANGE_RG_1     23     1891      734        2151
VM_RG_01    47    1801   2338      3586       69
VMWARE_RG11 33    1696   242       1712       24
VMWARE_RG_SP_02   18     1504      507        1512
```

From this I obtain only Top 10 Rg_name that are out grouped and their corresponding metrics with highest values like MaxRiops, MAXWiops etc,. The problem here is I find only MAXRiops column to be ordered as DESC. I would like to have other columns in DESC order aswell.

Comment: did the query worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `ROW_NUMBER` you can get top 10 bar1, bar2 values for each of the foo.

```
 with cte 
  as
  (
  select  foo, 
          bar1,
          bar2,
          ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by foo order by bar1 desc) seq1,  
          ROW_NUMBER() over (  partition by foo order by bar2 desc) seq2
  from Table1
  )
  select foo, bar1, bar2 from cte where seq1 <=10 or seq2 <=10
  order by bar1 desc, bar2 desc
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but I see similar problems like the one which I have updated. Only one column gets ordered by DESC and not the others.

Comment: @jain, VMWARE_RG12 has highest Riops, but VM_RG_01 gas highest wiops, so how can you have both the highest values in single table?

Comment: RADAR, oooh yes!! all these metrics are recorded at a particular timestamp and exists in a same table. I made this complicated. Thanks again for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have more columns that you want to select ?
i.e.

```
Select top 10 foo, Max(bar) Count1, Max(ABC) count2
from tbl
Group By foo, bar
Order By Count1 desc
```